# How to lengthen the vertical line in a table?

Tags: tables

How to lengthen the vertical line in a table to intersect the second hline, please?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{c|c} 
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Instrument & Date  \\
 \hline 
    &\\[-10pt]
A & 11.10. \\

 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{data_I}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing noalign and small skip

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself, but why do ou use `tabularx` without any `X` type column here? Wouldn't a simple `tabular` be sufficient here?

Comment: Because I need to set the width of table {0.95\textwidth}

Comment: Then, why not use \begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{c|X} instead? This modified code makes sure that too long entries in the second column are automatically split into multiple lines. If your entries are all short, just as the ones in your MWE, I don't see any need to artificially make the table that much wider than it naturally is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the vertical rules are never broken.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c} 
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Instrument & Date  \\
 \hline 
    &\\[-10pt]
A & 11.10. \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{data_I}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Three example of writing your simple table:

- with `tabularx` with centering right column defined by `tabularx`
- with `tabularx` with left aligned right column defined by `tabularx`
- with `tabular` with centering all table's columns

All examples use `\hhline` package for drawing top double rule.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hhline,makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|C}
    \hhline{=|=}
Instrument  & Date      \\
    \hline
A           & 11.10.    \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{data_I}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|L}
    \hhline{=|=}
Instrument  & Date      \\
    \hline
A           & 11.10.    \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{data_II}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \hhline{=|=}
Instrument  & Date      \\
    \hline
A           & 11.10.    \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{data_III}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note.*

- More details, how to write tables you can find on [enter link description here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). BTW, `nice3matrix is excellent package, however, for you simple table is somehow overkill solution. For learning learning how to write table, use "classic" packages are they are used in above MWE (Minimal Working Example) for table seems to be simpler.
- If you use `tabularx` table environment at least one column should be of `X` or from it derived column type as are done in above MWE.

Comment: Thank you very much